# creating a list of queues

Tags: c, list, linked-list, queue

I am working on a simulation. For this simulation I need 20 nodes (static) and then each node has a queue associated with it. This queue could hold any number of values. What would be the best way to implement this in C? I was aiming at having each of the queues being a simple linked list, but how can I effectively create several queues, one for each node??

Thanks,
Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to create one struct for the queue, which is a simple linked list:

```
typedef struct queue_t {
    int data; /* the date in the queue, can be anything, not only an int */
    struct queue_t* next; /* pointer to the next in the queue */
} queue_t;
```

And then another one is the list of 20 queues:

```
queue_t *list_of_queues[20];
```

That's the simplest way to go about it, IMHO.

**Edit:** Made the array of structs into an array of pointers

Comment: would you have to define a pointer to the head of the list, for each queue then? 
would that be list_of_queues[1] * HeadList = NULL

Comment: @stephen: I would change the above example to `struct queue_t* list_of_queues[20];` so that `list_of_queues[t]` would hold the top-of-queue pointer for node `t`.

Comment: @bta: I agree.  I changed the example as you suggested.